# Extract string between two strings

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

How can i extract randomstring between A & B. For example:

**A randomstring B**

Comment: I cannot speak for others, but I have problems to understand what you want. Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: @UweRaabe This should make it more clear :) Strings not chars! :)

Comment: BTW, one answer will be "regular expressions" because the question contains "extract" and "strings" ;)

Comment: @UweRaabe Kein problem ;)

Comment: I don't understand your question either. Give a concrete example please.

Comment: @whosrdaddy Whats hard to understand here? Extract a string between two strings?

Comment: Ok got it after reading Uwe's answer, Posted a regular expression solution ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming that "randomstring" doesn't contain the enclosing strings "A" or "B", you can use two calls to pos to extract the string:

```
function ExtractBetween(const Value, A, B: string): string;
var
  aPos, bPos: Integer;
begin
  result := '';
  aPos := Pos(A, Value);
  if aPos > 0 then begin
    aPos := aPos + Length(A);
    bPos := PosEx(B, Value, aPos);
    if bPos > 0 then begin
      result := Copy(Value, aPos, bPos - aPos);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The function will return an empty string when either A or B are not found.

Comment: Kudos for answering Uwe, because I still don't understand the question ;-)

Comment: I have a recursive version of this which populates a String Array... useful for extracting (for example) all Hyperlinks on a web page's source.

Comment: Note: `PosEx` comes from `StrUtils`

Answer (score 3):

Another approach:

```
function ExtractTextBetween(const Input, Delim1, Delim2: string): string;
var
  aPos, bPos: Integer;
begin
  result := '';
  aPos := Pos(Delim1, Input);
  if aPos > 0 then begin
    bPos := PosEx(Delim2, Input, aPos + Length(Delim1));
    if bPos > 0 then begin
      result := Copy(Input, aPos + Length(Delim1), bPos - (aPos + Length(Delim1)));
    end;
  end;
end;

Form1.Caption:= ExtractTextBetween('something?lol/\http','something?','/\http');
```

Result = lol

Comment: This might fail when Delim2 appears before or inside Delim1. If you can exclude this situation, your solution works, too. Btw: `Str` is the name of a built-in procedure and should be avoided for variable names.

Answer (score 3):

Answer with regular expression :)

```
uses RegularExpressions;
...
function ExtractStringBetweenDelims(Input : String; Delim1, Delim2 : String) : String;


var
  Pattern : String;
  RegEx   : TRegEx;
  Match   : TMatch;

begin
 Result := '';
 Pattern := Format('^%s(.*?)%s$', [Delim1, Delim2]);
 RegEx := TRegEx.Create(Pattern);
 Match := RegEx.Match(Input);
 if Match.Success and (Match.Groups.Count > 1) then
  Result := Match.Groups[1].Value;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ShowMessage(ExtractStringBetweenDelims('aStartThisIsWhatIWantTheEnd', 'aStart', 'TheEnd'));
end;
```

Comment: @NunoJemaio: the nice thing is that the same pattern would also work for case insensitive search (just add option to TRegEx.Create)

Comment: Will your method work if either the delim is = "" ? For example at the front or end of url's. This works perfect for middle string matching where both delims are not ""